# Loading jqxGrid with data from a WCF service returning JSON

Tags: jquery, json, wcf

Server side I'm using WCF returning properly formatted json.  I'm able to receive the expected data when I use a jquery $.ajax function, so let's assume (unless there's a nuance with jqWidgets) that the WCF side is correct.

What I can't get to work is loading a jqx dataAdapter with the same data.  I've tried a dozen different ways and always end up with no records.  Here's the javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).read(function() {
        var source = {
            type: "GET",
            data: "",
            dataType: "json",
            dataFields: [
                { name: "ID" },
                { name: "Name" }
            ],
            url: "TestService.svc/GetAttributes",
            root: 'GetAttributesResult'
        };

        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter( source );

        $("#jqxGrid").jqxGrid(
            {
                source: dataAdapter,
                columns: [
                    { text: 'ID', datafield: 'ID', width: 200},
                    { text: 'Name', datafield: 'Name', width: 200}
                ]
            });
    });
</script>
```

For reference the data being returned from my WCF service looks like this

```
{"GetAttributesResult":[{"ID":"1","Name":"Make"},{"ID":"2","Name":"Model"}]}
```

If I try something as simple as

```
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
```

I get an empty recordset while debugging with VS2012.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I'm open to taking a different design direction altogether as this is still early enough in the project to do so.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a help topic: [asp.net-web-service-grid.htm](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/asp.net-integration/asp.net-web-service-grid.htm). In addition, there's a typo: dataFields should be datafields.

Comment: Yeah, I've mulled over that page quite a bit before posting. I don't get any better results when I use the javascript on there.  It's a slightly different case though as it's written for consuming from .asmx (ASP.NET Webservices) vs .svc (WCF Services).  I'd think the client side would still apply though but so far I can't prove that it does.

Comment: Please, note that you have typo in the posted code.

Comment: I guess that it :(  I actually did note it the first time and corrected it but had already made other changes to sabotage the effort.  FWIW, dataType has to be datatype as well.  Thanks scripto!